# How can I add a paste handler to an IOleWindow in C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook add-in and what I want to do is to catch any files added to an email as the result of a cut&paste operation.

I already have an IntPtr to the target windowfor which I have a drag&drop handler registered.

So how do I go from a IntPtr to something I can pass into:
System.Windows.DataObject.AddPastingHandler()?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you are on the right track.  You may want to try [HwndSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.hwndsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) to convert the `IntPtr` to a dependency object, using `HWndSource.RootVisual`, but I doubt it.

You better hook to MailItem's [AttachmentAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.attachmentadd) event.

Comment: I cannot use the attachment add event because I need to be able to tell the difference between attachments added with the regular add attachment button, which I do not want to intercept, and ones being added via drag&drop or cut&paste.

Comment: Then try to create a WinForms add-in, not a WPF one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to intercept the Ctrl+V shortcut? You can try to patch the  GetClipboardData() Windows API function using, for example, a library like [Detours](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net).

Comment: Basically yes, I want to  intercept the Ctrl+V but I need to do it similar to the way that the drag&drop is handled: my handler keeps a reference to the original handler which I call if I do not handle the action myself.

Maybe this isn't even possible.

Comment: Of course you can do that - patch the function, do what you need to do, call the original function.

Comment: Of course you can do that - patch the function, do what you need to do, call the original function.

Comment: Of course you can do that - patch the function, do what you need to do, call the original function.